# Why am i getting the error saying "s undeclared here not in a function"

Tags: c, data-structures, stack, infix-notation

As you can see that in this code I am trying to convert from postfix to infix.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    double compute(char symbol,double op1,double op2)

    {
        switch(symbol)
        {
            case '+': return op1+op2;
            case '-': return op1-op2;
            case '*': return op1*op2;
            case '$':
            case '^': return (op1,op2);
    
        }
    }
    main()
    {
        double s[20],res,op1,op2;
        int top,i;
        char postfix[20];
        char symbol;
        printf("Enter postfix");
        scanf("%s",postfix);
        top=-1;
        for(i=0;i<stlen(postfix);i++)
            symbol=postfix[i];
        if(isdigit(symbol))
            s[++top]=symbol='0';
        else
        {
            op2=s[top--];
            op1=s[top--];
        }
        res=compute(symbol,op1,op2);
        s[++top]=res;
    }
    res=s[top--];
    printf("res is %d",res);
}
```

I maybe missing something in here as it shows `s` to be undeclared but as you can see that I have declared `s` in double after `main()`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please compile with `-Wall -Werror -Wextra` and follow the directions to fix the errors. Always put braces and use correct indentation for blocks like `for` loops and conditionals--the `for` loop "body" is only `symbol=postfix[i]` and everything after it is outside the loop body. A few other issues are present which the compiler will tell you about. Thanks.

Comment: yes you were right i had put the braces wrong

Comment: Most likely you are missing a brace `{` after your `for` loop line. Try : `for(i=0;i<stlen(postfix);i++) {`. Then fix the indenting.

Answer (score 0):

These three lines aren't in any scope:

```cpp
res = s[top--];
printf("res is %d", res);
}
```

That's why you have an error.

Comment: So what should i do in here then?

Comment: if you wan't to use them move them up from 1 line and delete the `}`.

Comment: yes you were right i fixed it and its running but there is another problem that whenever i am entering  a postfix like 12+ it gives me the result as a garbage value what is wrong please help!!

Comment: res is a `double` and whit `%d` you try to print an `int`, use `%f`

Comment: na still  not working it now shows bigger garbage values with decimal maybe something wrong in the code though.